# Is there a key or combo to edit a formula in Apple's Numbers without using the mouse?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, iwork-numbers

In Excel (and OpenOffice) I could use `F2` to edit the existing formula.  So far the only 'shortcut' I've found in Numbers involves clicking the mouse.  Since I'm going from moving with the keyboard to editing with the keyboard, I'd rather make the transition with the keyboard.  Are there undocumented or clever ways to trigger formula editing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documented way (Help > Keyboard Shortcuts) is to use Option-Return to start editing a cell.

Comment: Thanks.  Could have been a lot better placed in the shortcut list.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to assign any key you like using Keyboard Preferences to bind `Formula Editor` in Numbers